# Can somebody help me to draw this scheme using tikz trees, please?

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-trees

I want to draw this scheme

[image]

so I made this code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
                     draw, font=\small, align=center, fill=white},              
   level 1/.style = {sibling distance = 10em},% <-- new
   level 2/.style = {sibling distance = 9em},% <-- new
   level 3/.style = {sibling distance = 8em},% <-- new
   level 4/.style = {sibling distance = 8em},% <-- new
]
\node {Estabilidade de Sistemas\\Elétricos de Potência}
    [edge from parent fork down]
    child {node {Estabilidade do\\Ângulo do Rotor}
        child {node {Estabilidade Angular\\a Pequenos Distúrbios}}
        child {node {Estabilidade\\Transitória}
            child {node {Curto Prazo}}}}
    child {node{Estabilidade de\\Frequência}
        child{node{Curto Prazo}}
        child{node{Longo Prazo}}}
    child {node{Estabilidade\\de Tensão}
           child {node{Estabilidade de\\Tensão a Grandes\\Perturbações}
                child {node{Curto Prazo}}}
           child {node {Estabilidade de\\Tensão a Pequenas\\Perturbações}
                child {node{Longo Prazo}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But I'm getting this

[image]

I don't know how to make two nodes have the same childs and make the correct vertical spacings.

Please, help me!

Comment: Welcome! Would using `forest` be an option?

Comment: This is not formally a tree, so you'll have to do some manual work to make multidominant roots. But the base tree methods in TikZ are unfortunately never ideal, since they do no automatic positioning. As @Schrödinger'scat suggests, it would be better to use `forest`.  But since this is not a tree see e.g. [Lost in the Forest -- Merging after Branching?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/438574) for some ideas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not a perfect solution. Used `missing` `child` to ‘make’ two nodes have the same child.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
                     draw, font=\small, align=center, fill=white},              
   level 1/.style = {sibling distance = 10em},% <-- new
   level 2/.style = {sibling distance = 9em},% <-- new
   level 3/.style = {sibling distance = 8em},% <-- new
   level 4/.style = {sibling distance = 8em},% <-- new
]
\node {Estabilidade de Sistemas\\Elétricos de Potência}
    [edge from parent fork down]
    child {node {Estabilidade do\\Ângulo do Rotor}
        child {node {Estabilidade Angular\\a Pequenos Distúrbios}
child[missing] child{}}
        child {node {Estabilidade\\Transitória}
            child {node[xshift=-3.6mm] {Curto Prazo}}child[missing]}}
    child {node{Estabilidade de\\Frequência}
child{child{
        child{node{Curto Prazo}}
        child{node{Longo Prazo}}}}}
    child {node{Estabilidade\\de Tensão}
           child {node{Estabilidade de\\Tensão a Grandes\\Perturbações}
                child[missing]  child[missing] child {node{Curto Prazo}}}
           child {node {Estabilidade de\\Tensão a Pequenas\\Perturbações}
                child {node{Longo Prazo}}child[missing] child[missing]
}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Just a quick note: include `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` so the accented glyphs are visible. `:)`

Comment: Thanks for the update! I wish I could +1 again! `:)`

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[edges]{forest}


\begin{document}


\begin{forest}
  for tree={align=c,draw,rounded corners, tier/.option=level, anchor=base, l sep'+=10pt},
  forked edges,
  before typesetting nodes={
    where content={}{phantom}{}
  },
  before drawing tree={
    where n children=0{
      if={>O{!u.phantom}}{
        tikz+={\draw (!up.parent anchor) -- +(0pt,-\foresteoption{fork sep}) -| (.child anchor) (!un.parent anchor) -- +(0pt,-\foresteoption{fork sep}) -| (.child anchor);}
      }{}
    }{}
  },
  [Estabilidade de Sistemas\\Elétricos de Potência
    [Estabilidade do\\Ângulo do Rotor
      [Estabilidade Angular\\a Pequenos Distúrbios[]]
      [ 
        [Curto Prazo]
      ]
      [Estabilidade\\Transitória[]]
    ]
    [Estabilidade de\\Frequência
    [\strut\\\strut\\\strut, draw=none, child anchor/.option=parent anchor 
        [Curto Prazo]
        [Longo Prazo]
      ]
    ]
    [Estabilidade\\de Tensão
      [Estabilidade de\\Tensão a Grandes\\Perturbações[]]
      [
        [Curto Prazo]
        [Longo Prazo]
      ]
      [Estabilidade de\\Tensão a Pequenas\\Perturbações[]]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks! It is a good alternative to solve the problem!

Comment: Nice answer, as always! +1 from me, cwac! `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda Cwac cwac ;). Diolch yn fawr!